Case sensitive in VB.NET
I have a project in VB.NET where I have installed the Microsoft.Graph NuGet package (v5.58.0). This package contains two classes with nearly the same name, differing only by one capital letter: PlannerChecklistItem and PlannerCheckListItem.  In C#, I can work with this without any problem, but in VB.NET (which is case-insensitive) it throws the following error:

'PlannerChecklistItem' is ambiguous in 'Microsoft.Graph.Models' namespace

The error occurs as soon as you use the class:
Dim checklistItem As New PlannerChecklistItem 

Is there any way to make VB.NET case-sensitive for this line? Is there a workaround to use this package in VB.NET?
I have noticed that PlannerCheckListItem (with a capital "L") is marked as obsolete. Another approach could be to instruct VB.NET to ignore obsolete classes. Is that possible?
One potential solution could be to create a separate project in C# and wrap PlannerChecklistItem in a new class, then use that class in VB.NET. However, I would prefer a workaround with less impact than mixing C# and VB.NET in the same solution.
I have seen these two questions, but neither of them provides a solid solution to my problem, beyond creating a C# project in the same solution as my existing VB project (and that's precisely what I want to avoid):
Dealing with case sensitive name collisions in VB.net
How do I handle case sensitive classes and methods from a c# web service in my VB.net app

possible duplicate of Dealing with case sensitive name collisions in VB.net

It's funny that MS violates their own guidance.

possible duplicate of How do I handle case sensitive classes and methods from a c# web service in my VB.net app

Are they both in the same namespace? If not, just qualify them when you refer to them.

@DaveDoknjas Yes, they are in the same namespace

@GSerg one of the questions you provide as duplicated, has not any accepted answer. The other one the only accepted answer is precisely to create a C# project in the same solution.

@Carlos Correct. Sometimes the options you have are not the ones you want.

You could add a small C# project written to act as a wrapper for the unfortunately named method. It isn't immediately obvious to me where to report the bug.

@AndrewMorton https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/2685

I have finally used this workaround:
Dim nameOfPlannerChecklistItem As String = "Microsoft.Graph.Models.PlannerChecklistItem, Microsoft.Graph"
Dim typeOfPlannerChecklistItem As Type = Type.GetType(nameOfPlannerChecklistItem)
Dim checklistItem As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(typeOfPlannerChecklistItem)


I have found a solution with reflection:
Dim nameOfPlannerChecklistItem As String = "Microsoft.Graph.Models.PlannerChecklistItem, Microsoft.Graph"
Dim typeOfPlannerChecklistItem As Type = Type.GetType(nameOfPlannerChecklistItem)
Dim checklistItem As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(typeOfPlannerChecklistItem)

I guess Microsoft will fix the bug, but meanwhile this is a valid workaround
